# Process UIImage and return it within a block

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage, objective-c-blocks

I have a method that sets the image for an UIImageView in a UITableViewCell asynchronously. The method is as follows:

```
__weak ProductTableCell *weakCell = cell;
__weak ProductsViewController *weakSelf = self;

[CommonHandlers setImageForItemId:[product stringID] withImageURL:product.imageURL forImageView:cell.imageView withImagesCache:self.imageCache completionBlock:^UIImage *(UIImage *img) {

        ProductTableCell *localCell = weakCell;
        ProductsViewController *localSelf = weakSelf;

        // New image view that will contain both layers
        UIImageView *mergedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];

        // Place imageView layer over, this is the sticker layer drawn elsewhere
        CALayer *discountLayer = localCell.imageView.layer;

        // Merge layers
        [mergedImageView.layer addSublayer:discountLayer];

        // Get image from both layers
        UIImage *flattenedImage = [ImageHandlers imageFromLayer:mergedImageView.layer];

        return flattenedImage;
    }];
```

Within the block taken by this method, I take the image when downloaded and merge it with a sticker layer on top of the product image.

Within `setImageForItemId: withImageURL: forImageView: withImagesCache: completionBlock:^UIImage *(UIImage *)` I perform the usual `dispatch_async` stuff to download the image asynchronously, and when it is downloaded, I call the above block within it:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                    UIImage *imageThumb = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData
```

dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl]];

```
                    if (imageThumb) {

                        if (imageBlock) {
                            UIImage *processedImage = imageBlock(imageThumb);
                            if (processedImage) {
                                [imagesCache setObject:processedImage forKey:stringID];
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                             [imagesCache setObject:imageThumb forKey:stringID];
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        NSLog(@"Returned image is null!");
                    }

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        ...
                        imageView.image = imagesCache[stringID];
                    });
                });
```

Although stepping through the code in debug reveals the image is downloaded and merged correctly with the sticker, and then set within the imageCache dictionary the resulting imageView image is nil.

Any ideas on why this happens? I tried to create the processed image on the heap but this did not work either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be careful, I assume imagesCache is an NSMutableDictionary, which is not thread safe. You're setting values to it in a background thread and read on the main thread. Perhaps this is the source of your problems.

Comment: Could be. I have changed my implementation and use SDWebImageManager to download and cache resources now. I will need to go back and check your suggestion though. Thank you.